# clearing session after destroy a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working with an admin user in Chrome and a regular user in another browser. After I as admin destroy one of the regular users, I  tried to reopen the application in the browser the destroyed user was using. However, I got this error message

```
Couldn't find Twitteruser with id=2
```

So the session's living on in the browser after the user's destroyed

The session's created like this

```
 def create
  twitteruser = Twitteruser.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
  session[:twitteruser_id] = twitteruser.id
  redirect_to twitterquestions_url, notice: "Signed in!"
end
```

In the application_controller, it current user's created like this

```
   def current_user
         @current_user ||= Twitteruser.find(session[:twitteruser_id]) if    session[:twitteruser_id]
  end
```

This is the destroy action

```
 def destroy
    Twitteruser.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_url
 end
```

Based on other SO answers I found, I tried to reset the session two different ways, but they both reset the session of the admin user, not the user who was destroyed

```
 def destroy
    Twitteruser.find(params[:id]).destroy
    #1. session[:twitteruser_id] = nil destroys my own session, not deleted users
    #2. reset_session  #reset admin's session
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to twitterusers_url
 end
```

I also tried to pass an argument to reset_session but it doesn't accept them.

Can anyone tell me how to clear the destroyed user's session? Thanks

Comment: It seems that you can be only User and you (User) are about to clear the session of the Twitteruser. Then how it is possible when you do `session[:twitteruser_id] = nil` to clear your own session?

Comment: sorry, mistake in the OP. There is no User, only Twitteruser. I fixed it now. That's not the cause of the problem with the session.

Comment: How the app knows that you are `Admin`? Is this a sign_out action or Twitteruser deletion ?

Comment: The app knows I'm admin because there is an admin field on each user. The delete user link is only visible to users who have the admin boolean set to true.  So, in Chrome browser, I'm signed in as a user with the admin boolean set to true, and I delete the account of another user from the list of users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what your using for backing your sessions. If the session is in the Cookie then there's nothing your Admin can do with it as there's nothing server side to work with. Irregardless, messing with someone else's session may not be possible as you won't know the session ID.

What you want to do is either catch the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` that is thrown by find or use find_by_id which will return nil. When the user tries to access the site with the session referencing a deleted user, you can then kill the session.

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= Twitteruser.find(session[:twitteruser_id]) if session[:twitteruser_id]
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  session[:twitteruser_id] = nil # or reset_session
end
```

or

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= fetch_user(session[:twitteruser_id])
end

def fetch_user(id)
  Twitteruser.find_by_id(id) || reset_session unless id.nil?
end
```

This will work regardless of how a Twitteruser gets deleted. For example, imagine if you deleted the user from the rails console where there is no session.

Comment: actually, I'm using MyApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store . Would you mind updating your answer to include directions for this scenario (but please leave the information already provided, as I'd like to learn from it).  thanks if you can help a bit more.

Comment: I appended the first paragraph. The same answer applies regardless of the session store.

Comment: Thanks a lot. shouldn't the session be set to nil in the rescue in your first example? otherwise why is it an alternative to reset_session

Comment: Actually, your second example (I haven't tried the first) doesn't achieve the desired results. As admin using Chrome browser, I destroy the user. In Firefox, I refresh the browser and the signed in user is no longer signed in because it has been destroyed. But if I click sign-in with Twitter, the destroyed user can sign back in, (and then also reappears in the list of users for the admin to destroy in Chrome browser).

Comment: when I say the destroyed user can sign back in, I mean that he can do it without having to give permissions again to Twitter. Same thing happens with your first solution (that I just tested now)

Comment: Well that would be correct wouldn't it? If they log in again then it will create a new Twitteruser, same as the first time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24597/discussion-between-cluster-and-michael)